# How to swap fadeIn/fadeOut of dynamically created selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am swapping out divs generated with a php foreach loop like this...

```
<img class="trigger" name="showme-<?php echo $stuff ?> ... >

<div id="showme-<?php echo $stuff ?>" style="display:none"></div>

$('.trigger').click(function(){
    var num=$(this).attr("name");
    $('#'+num).fadeIn();
```

This works fine.. but my question is how do I not just fade in these elements but also fade out the ones that are currently sitting there so I am only showing one showme-var div at a time?  Because I do not know which one is currently showing I can not use the selector to identify who needs  to be faded out.  Can I add a wildcard "*" to the selector or maybe use .children of a parent div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap all of these fadeIn/Out divs with a parent element, then you can simply grab all the siblings:

```
$('#' + num).fadeIn().siblings().fadeOut();
```

Provided there's nothing else in the same div of course.

Answer (score 0):

Put a common class on the elements being faded in/out, and use that:

```
<div class="showHide" id="showme-<?php echo $stuff ?>" style="display:none"></div>
```

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
    var num=$(this).attr("name");
    var shown = $('#'+num).fadeIn();      //show this one
    $('.showHide').not( shown ).fadeOut();  // hide all except for this one
```

Ultimately, the best solution will depend on your actual markup. If you provide more, you'll get a more accurate solution.